# Export results of as.undirected in igraph to a data frame

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

I have converted a directed graph to an undirected one in igraph using as.undirected. I now want to export this to a data frame so I can look through the edges and weight. However, when I try to do so using as_data_frame I end up with a corrupted data frame, using both the default "what" option and "both". I can't really share the data, but below is the code I'm using. Is there another way to do this?

```
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed = TRUE)
E(g)$weight <- edges$weightvar
g2 <- as.undirected(g, mode = "collapse", edge.attr.comb = igraph_opt("sum"))
out <- as_data_frame(g2, what = "both")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `edge.attr.comb = "sum"`, rather than `igraph_opt("sum")`, and you find the use of `igraph_opt` by typing `?igraph_opt` in the console.

As you can see

```
> igraph_opt("edge.attr.comb")
$weight
[1] "sum"

$name
[1] "concat"

[[3]]
[1] "ignore"
```